# MS Access 2016 - Opening report based on current record

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, report

I could do with some help with the final touches to my music store database, and it should come across as a very easy question to answer. My VBA programming primer book just arrived in the mail and I've searched the event procedure section for answers, as well as referring to these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openreport-method-access

https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/690040-open-report-based-current-record

My problem here is as follows:

**I'm trying to open a report in Access that only shows the data from *one* order when the Review button is pressed (see picture).**

[New Order form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgvCF.jpg)

Access is instead giving me the whole catalogue of orders (see picture).

[Order report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhT24.jpg)

This is no good, and it is occurring even after I implemented the following code:

[VBA code - event procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWFvp.jpg)

I.e.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptOrder", acViewPreview, , , , "OrderID = " & Me.OrderID
```

Can anyone help? What might I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**- LC**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where clause should be in the 4th position.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptOrder", acViewPreview, , "OrderID = " & Me.OrderID
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that was just for SQL statements... when I do it like that, I get a syntax error, "missing operator in query expression."

Comment: Can I apply some code to the report's "On Load" event procedure instead? Would that do it?

Comment: _I get a syntax error_ which means that either OrderID is not present in the report, or no value was held in Me.OrderID.

Comment: With the code I cited above in the event procedure of the Review button? Or when you tried to add that code to a report? I'm certain it wouldn't work as is in a report's On Load event procedure, but I am just wondering if there's anything I can do to be able to access the form's order data from the relevant report apart from what I'm trying already.